# Is it possible to know if firebase auth is from android app or iphone app or web app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to know if when there's an firebase authentification, it's possible to get the source of this authentification?
To know if it's from my iphone app, android app or web app.
Why :
My web app isn't on the web, but on local server. I want to distribute this web app with server (It's for a personnal project but it could have 10 prototypes). So everybody can get my firebase config. And I don't want that someone can create account from the web firebase api because I accept google/apple and email/password auth. I can't disable email/password for my project purpose.
I hope this is clear.
To be more clear, if the email/password auth is created, is it possible to know if it's from android app or iphone app or webapp?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided APIs for Firebase Auth don't give any indication which platform was used to create the account.  Firebase intends for all accounts to work across all platforms using the provided SDKs and APIs accessible for each platform.

If you want to record your own per-user data in a database, you're free to do that.  Note that this is not really "secure" in that each user could effectively manipulate your database or APIs to indicate whatever they want about their platform.  If you do not have this sort of security in mind, then you can simply trust your own code to write, and late read, the user's platform in a database after they sign up.

Comment: Thanks, I know we can sign apple and google app with sha-256, it's not possible to get this information when an user is created ? I think the best solution for me it's to delete email/password auth and create custom token ( don't know how, but we'll see) because create a new table with users and platform attributes is too unsecure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get this information".  Everything that's available is seen in the API documentation.  If you don't see something there (like a SHA-256 hash), then it's just not available and you'll have to come up with it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> To be more clear if the email/password auth is created, is it possible to know if it's from the Android app or iPhone app, or web app?

Yes, it's possible. Let's say we want to know if a user has signed in from Android. When the user creates an account from an Android device, most likely you are storing user data as objects in the database. The simplest solution I can think of is to add another property in your User class, called "platform" and set it to "Android". If the user signs up with an iPhone, then set the property to "iOS". Same thing for the web. Knowing that the user might change the device, every time the user opens the app check that value against the OS the user is using. If the OS is changed, also change the value accordingly. This way you'll always know the OS the user is using. If you allow the users to use multiple platforms, for Android, there is a function called [getProviderData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderData()):

> Returns a List of UserInfo objects that represents the linked identities of the user using different authentication providers that may be linked to their account.

Similar functions can be found for the other platforms as well.